# ConstraintLayout vs. android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Just starting out with constraint layouts and hopefully a simple question.

In an XML layout file, is there any difference between using

```
<ConstraintLayout ...
```

vs.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout ...
```

Is one of them preferred over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use the 2nd one.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

Please refer to the Android [documentation](http://%3Candroid.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout) for more information

*Note: ConstraintLayout is available as a support library that you can use on Android systems starting with API level 9 (Gingerbread). As such, we are planning on enriching its API and capabilities over time. This documentation will reflect those changes.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I will continue with the second one.  Seems Android Studio accepts the syntax of the first one but it does not work.  So the second one is the way to go.